# return false is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have simple javascript functions which executing a simple string based on some data. Javascript functions i am using are

```
function checkdata() {
    var data = document.getElementById('data').value;
    if (data != '') {
        console.log("Hello");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function gotothen() {
    console.log("Bye");
}

function changemode(value) {
    if (value == 0) {
        checkdata();
        gotothen();
    }
    if (value == 1) {
        checkdata();
        gotothen();
    }
}
```

and the html code i am using are

```
<input type="text" name="data" id="data">
<a href="javacript:void(0)" onclick="changemode(0)">Hotel</a>
<a href="javacript:void(1)" onclick="changemode(1)">Flight</a>
```

so if i enter any value to textbox and click on any of the hyperlink it calls `changemode()` function. there are two function i am calling in `changemode()` function. One is `checkdata()` and the other is `gotothen()`. So if textbox value is not blank then it should not call `gotothen()` function but it is calling. It should stop after printing "Hello" only but it is calling `gotothen()` function too after using return false. So how can i stop the execution of `gotothen()` function if text-box value is not blank ?

Comment: You `return` a value from `checkdata()`. That does ***not*** automatically `return` and abort the code in `changemode()`. You're not doing anything with the return value from `checkdata`. You're literally calling `checkdata` and then *unconditionally* call `gotothen`; each and every time.

Comment: so basically return false will not work in this case ?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code is returning `false` but not actually using that.

You'll want a piece of logic like

```
if(checkdata()){
  gotothen();
}
```

and you can put it on the outside of your changemode block, like this:

```
function changemode(value) {
    if( checkdata()){
        if(value == 0) {
            gotothen();
        }
        if(value == 1) {
            gotothen();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `gotothen()` no matter what. The result from checkdata() doesn't change anything. You don't usr it in the `changemode()` function, and the `changemode` function is the one that should eventually return true or false.

You should change your code so that the result from `checkdata()` is the condition to calling `gotothen()`. It should be:

```
if (checkdata())
    gotothen();
// ... further execution
```

Answer (score 2):

because function checkdata has return value, you should capture it for deciding to call gotothen or not.

```
var check = checkdata();

if (check != false) {
    gotothen();
}
```

or simplify that to:

```
if (checkdata() != false) gotothen();
```

and we can simplify again:

```
if (true_value != false) ...
```

with:

```
if (true_value) ...
```